# Adding one element in array in React-Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a project, where I use `react-redux`, and I have a reducer, which by idea should add one element in array and return new array. How I can do this?

```js
/*---- Reducer ----*/
case CHANGE_EVENT_USERS:
  return { ...state, users: payload };
 
/*---- Here's my hopeless tryings ----*/

userClickHandler() {
  const { id, homeFloor, avatarUrl, login } = this.props;
  const user = { id, homeFloor, avatarUrl, login };
  this.props.changeEventUsers([...user]); // []
  this.props.changeEventUsers(this.props.event.users.push()); // number
}
```

Comment: use push method for array

Comment: @Hushme, also tried

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but from my understanding the solution to your problem would look something like this:

```
case CHANGE_EVENT_USERS:
  return { ...state, users: [ ...state.users, action.payload ] };
```

Answer (score 2):

I like better the syntax of concat.
In your reducer do:

```
case CHANGE_EVENT_USERS:
  return users.concat(action.payload);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the add directly in the reducer.

From your component

```
this.props.changeEventUsers(newUser); // add the new user
```

In the reducer

```
return { ...state, users: [...state.users, payload] };
```

I made the assumption that "payload" contains the info coming from the action and the `users` array is by default initialised with an empty array value `[]`

Comment: in initial state I assign hole array, that why I try don't mess with reducer

Comment: @RamzanChasygov try the above example. You should hold the entire array in reducer and only manipulate it there. That's the purpose of reducers. You shouldn't to manipulations inside the react components.

So at the beginning of the reducer where you define the initial state define it with `users: []`, and subsequent additions should be done via the `CHANGE_EVENT_USERS` action

Comment: In initial state I need use object and `users` is one of this key

Answer (score 1):

Use `concat()`

```
const initialArray = [1, 2, 3];  
const elemenToAdd = 4; 
const newArray= initialArray.concat([elementToAdd]);
```

> [1, 2, 3, 4]

Notice I'm using `const` here to emphasize that the initial array was not mutated.

The great thing about the method above, it's that it can be used to chain operations together.
    `result = initialArray.concat(..).filter(..).concat(..);`
(where `..` represents skipped code details)

You can also use `concat` by passing in arrays as parameters:
`newArray = concat(initialArray, [elementToadd])`

Or use es7 spread operator syntax for array concatenating:
`newArray = [...initialArray, elementToAdd, ...[5], [6] ];`

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [6] ]

Use `...` to send individual elements of the supplied array to be elements in the new array; without the dots, the supplied array is itself the element.

So in the your case, the line in question could be written as:

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution:

```
this.props.changeEventUsers([...this.props.event.users, user]);
```